# firebase + facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, firebase

(I am creating a new question cause it will be easy for others to find it)

have got the login to work with firebase. trying to get access to the open graph data on the client side itself.

I have the user access Token thanks to the firebase sdk. Now I have permission to get access to the user likes.

(I have never used FB open graph before and all the examples are done using the FBphp sdk)

```
            var myDataRef = new Firebase('my firebase');
            var temp;           
            var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(myDataRef, function(error, user) {
                if (error) {
                    // an error occurred while attempting login
                    console.log('an error occurred:');
                    console.log(error);
                } else if (user) {
                    // user authenticated with Firebase
                    console.log('logged in:');
                    console.log(user.accessToken);
                    temp=user.accessToken;

    /*look here*/   $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/'+ user.id +'/likes?access_token='+temp+'', function(data) {
                    console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);

                 } else {
                       // user is logged out
                       console.log('logged out');
                 }
            });
```

The request is successful but the data returned is not being displayed, all I am getting is [Object object] in console. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You may want to check out [Singly](http://www.singly.com), which works with Firebase and provides full access to Facebook APIs.

Comment: @Kato thanks I got stuck with singly, but I made some progress with this example. I think I am almost there. can u tell me why is it that I am not getting the data

Comment: @user2135104 Try using `data.data` rather than `data` alone, corresponding to the Graph API documentation for paginated results (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/).

Comment: @RobDiMarco u wont believe me "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],"....this was the response....clearly its returning the likes but why cant I see them. data.paging gives a response [object object] ........is it something to do with the "access token" u told me to use

Comment: To see the response, replace the plus sign with a comma. Whenever you see [object Object] it means the object is being converted to a string to display. This happens implicitly if you try to concatenate it to a string. Use this instead: console.log("Data Loaded:", data);

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you actually are getting some useful data back, but `console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);` is converting that data to the string `[Object object]`

To see the contents of your data, try logging with this instead: `console.log(data)` or use a [breakpoint](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints) in your developer tools to inspect it during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

you are using json, just use console.log("Data Loaded: " + JSON.stringify(data));